# Parse API for Php

Tags: php, mysql, parse-platform

I am currently working on one application which is using parse API in php. The scenario is I am having 3 tables named `User`, `Kids` and `JournalEntry`. `User` has many `Kids` and `Kids` has many `Journal Entry`. So its like `Kids` table has `User Pointer` and `JounralEntry` also has 2 pointers named `KidsID` and `UserID`. When I try to get the data from the `JournalEntry` table, it is taking too much time because of the 2 queries which I fire. First query for fetching the data from the `kids` table and second one is for the `JournalEntry` table on the basis of first query's `objectid`.

Is there any way in Parse API that we can directly fire one query like following:

```
SELECT * FROM JounralEntry
WHERE Kids.objectId = JounralEntry.kidsID AND User.objectId = JounralEntry.UserID ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Relational Queries](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries-relational-queries) to achieve that

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: " \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"KidsId":{"$inQuery":{"where":{REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_QUERY_HERE},"className":"Kids"}}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/JounralEntry
```

Please correct any wrong field in the query.

Comment: Hi kodingralph, I appreciate your answer but my problem is I have to find related kidsID from the user's table and then on the basis of that result i can fire query on the journalEntry table to match the first queries result with jounralEnrty's kidsID.

Comment: You can still use `Relational Queries`. What you need to use is `$inQuery` parameter. Check my edited answer for example or in the docs I posted. If you still had issues, adjust your question with a more detailed use case.